# RealmResults Query Returns Partial Results - Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I am having a very strange behavior while querying data from my Realm table.

**Example**

I have an object called `OrderItem` defined like this:

```
public class OrderItem extends RealmObject{

   @PrimaryKey
   @Index
   private long id;

   //the rest of the fields here
   //then getters and setters as usual
}
```

The issue is quite unpredictable; because sometimes:

```
RealmResults<OrderItem> items = realm.where(OrderItem.class)
       .equalTo("order_id", order_id)
       .findAllSorted("id");
```

returns incomplete results - especially by 1 row;

This has been driving me nuts because I cannot exactly find out how it returns such partial results; doesn't matter how many rows I have in the said table!

**NOTE**

A while back, I was using a `String` type as the primary key in my table until I learned how bad an idea that was when trying to increment values; so I switched to **long** type which is fine; except now I get partial results from the query above!

I will truly appreciate your help on this! Any ideas, tips that could help me mitigate this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Eenvincible!

Comment: What thread are you doing the query where you get inconsistent results? Is it in `doInBackground()` or something similar? Show code around the inconsistent query.

Comment: Corresponding github issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5153

Comment: I use a service (background service to be exact) then execute the code inside a serviceHandler;

Comment: I am not testing with `realm.refresh()` as suggested by the guys over on github then report back

Comment: I meant to say I am `testing` not the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the database after switching primary key type?
You can do this with:

```
Realm.deleteRealm();
```

I had some similar troubles with Realm database. Deleting and creating new database helped.

Comment: The switch was a very long time back; so it cannot be that; I have even reinstalled the app afresh

Comment: I see. It is hard for me to say what might be wrong. The only thing that comes to my mind now is to try to use another variant of the .findAllSorted() method.
In your case it will be:
.findAllSorted("id",Sort.ASCENDING);

Comment: Why would the sort criterium have any effect on the number of results?

Comment: Same thing I asked myself Tim!!